# Did Naulakha cost more than Burj Khalifa?

Tags: architecture, mughals

Naulakha Pavilion in Lahore fort (made 1631-1633) is famous for 9 lakh (0.9 Million) rupees spent in its development. [Rajput (1963), pp. 8-9]

I am interested to know what will be its worth today (approximately) and will it cost more than Burj Khalifa (cost 1.5$ bn) *[USAToday](http://content.usatoday.com/communities/ondeadline/post/2010/01/dubai-opens-world-tallest-building/1)* or not?

Comment: Links would improve this question.

Comment: It is a kind of an apples to oranges comparation. We could get an estimate of how many resources it took to build it then, but that would be meaningless because today we would neither use the same techniques nor need the same resources. You cannot say something to the tune of "since it took 1.000.000 days*workers and today a worker earns $100 a day, nowadays it would cost $100.000.000"

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree it can never be equal. That's why i used the word approximation here. Fair point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Taj Mahal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taj_Mahal) was also built under the same ruler, [Shah Jahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Jahan), and at about the same time. The wiki entry for the Taj Mahal gives us an idea of the values involved then, and now:

> The Taj Mahal complex is believed to have been completed in its
>   entirety in 1653 at a cost estimated at the time to be around 32
>   million rupees, which in 2015 would be approximately 52.8 billion
>   rupees (US$827 million).

If my math works out, at the above mentioned conversion rate I get 900,000 rupees then= 1,485,000,000 rupees today, or $22,985,839.80 [US dollars](https://www.google.com/search?q=conversion%20rupee%20to%20us%20Dollars&oq=conversion%20rupee%20to%20us%20Dollars&aqs=chrome..69i57.12172j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), so less then the $1.5 billion mentioned in the question.